# Помогите справиться с заданием

Tags: c++, исключения, try-catch

Создать программу, которая демонстрирует, что функция со своим собственным try-блоком не должна перехватывать все возможные исключения, выброшенные в блоке try. Некоторые исключения могут быть выпущены во внешние области действия и обрабатываться в них.

Я так понял здесь нужно чтобы при выходе из функции был еще один catch для обработки другой ситуации. Подскажите как это реализовать. Тут синтаксически неправильно. Ругается.

```
void Foo(int& a)
{
try
{
    if (a > 0)
        throw 1;
    else
        throw "Digit is negative!\n\n";
}
catch (int & res)
{
    cout << "Digit is positive!\n\n";
}
}
void main()
{
int a;
cout << "Enter digit:";
cin >> a;
Foo(a);
catch (char * res)
{
    cout << *res << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Ну вы же все написали - в функции перехватываете не все, что генерируете (или регенерируете исключение в catch-блоке), а потом снаружи демонстрируете, что исключение таки вышло за пределы функции. С такой постановкой вопроса - сделайте - вы на грани фола - закрытия как учебного задания, перекладываемого на чужие плечи :)

Comment: Что-то не получается синтаксически реализовать

Comment: Взгляните внимательно, что пишет вам VS2017 (если вы в ней работаете), как правило, там все четко написано где у вас проблема.

Comment: Ответ вам уже дали. На заметку, лучше не бросайте как исключения в `throw` типы, не предназначенные для этого (будь то `int`, `char` и т.п.). Используйте специальные типы-наследники `std::exception`, созданные специально для этих целей, или, если это необходимо, создавайте свой тип, наследуясь от все того-же `std::exception`. Конечно, можно написать еще и свой базовый тип для исключений, но это уже совсем другая история :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кроме пары мелочей главное - вы не написали блок `try`, а только `catch` в функции `main`...

```
void Foo(int a)
{
    try
    {
        if (a > 0)
            throw 1;
        else
            throw "Digit is negative!\n\n";
    }
    catch (int)
    {
        cout << "Digit is positive!\n\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Enter digit:";
    cin >> a;
    try
    {
        Foo(a);
    }
    catch (const char * res)
    {
        cout << res << endl;
    }
}
```